# Tcl: How to append multiple variables to a single line with a space between them?

Tags: tcl

Below code, append can add all file paths to a single line, but there is no space between them.
How to add a space between each path?

```
set all_path ""

foreach line $lines {
   set filepath [proc_get_file_path $line]
   ...
   #some commands
   ...
   append ::all_path $filepath
}
```

Expected output:

```
../path/a ../path/b ../path/c ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to use `all_path` later on?

From the distance, this is where you would like to use a Tcl list:

```
set all_path [list]

foreach line $lines {
   set filepath [proc_get_file_path $line]
   # ...
   lappend all_path $filepath
}
```

The string representation of Tcl lists would also match your expectation re a whitespace delimiter. You can also assemble such a string manually, with `append` introducing a whitespace explicitly: `append all_path " " $filepath`. But maybe, this is not what you want to begin with ...

Comment: lappend will add each path to a new line. This is the original code. But I found an issue with this. A tool can't resolve Verilog `include if analyze each verilog file separately. So I want to pass all source files in a single line.

Comment: `lappend` does not add new line characters, or anything like that. did you read the `lappend` manpage? It stores a value at the tail of a Tcl list. If someone decides to turn this into a line-separated string rep, then one would have to run `join $all_path \n` explicitly.

Comment: @Fisher This answer, as is, is answering the question you asked. However it seems that your actual problem is different from your question, which makes it difficult to answer. I'd encourage you to include more information in your question to help others better understand your problem. Otherwise, no one will understand your actual problem and you will be unlikely to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, lappend is working. The problem is in the tcl script there is a proc_output_file, it will convert each item to a new line. After add proc_output_file_single_line, it's working fine.